# Variable will be instantiated more than once

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I got something unusual when developing a small web server using **Python2.7+Apache+mod_wsgi**. The main usage of this server is:

1. Receiving regular requests from another server(server A), and put the request body into DB.
2. Using some background threads to parse the request body in DB and send the parsed information to a third server(server B).

Apache is configured as **Windows 'winnt' MPM** mode. Code of dispatch.py, which is the entry point, is like below:

```
from urlparse import parse_qs

pool = MyThreadClass() # A customized thread class to parse request body in DB
pool.start()

def application(environ, start_response):
    # Receiving regular request from server A and put request body into BD
    output = 'OK'
    start_response('200OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return [output]
```

At the beginning, the thread class is created when the server starts up and it runs perfectly. However, **several hours later**, I found the thread class (MyThreadClass) will be instantiated again, which means at that moment there will be **two** MyThreadClass instances running background.
I don't know if it's correct to create instance like this when Apache starts up. Do you get any ideas?

**[edit1]** Below is the config for wsgi part in apache:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / "E:/eclipse workspace/SubscriptionServer/src/business/dispatcher.py"
WSGIPythonPath "E:/eclipse workspace/SubscriptionServer/src"

<Directory "E:/eclipse workspace/SubscriptionServer">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**[edit2]** I have followed the instruction @Graham gave and set LogLevel to "info". I think I have find the cause but can't explain why!
Below are the logs for access log and error log. My server is listening to 8080. The first three lines of error.log are logged when server starts up. However, in access log at the time **16:36:18 2011**, there is a call from 124.237.78.181 to request http://g.ha99y.com/R.asp?P=123.157.218.85:8080. Just at that time, in error log, the server load dispatcher.py again. I can't explain where does that call come from and why it creates two interpreters 'myhost.com:8080|' and 'myhost.com|'.

***access.log:***

```
124.237.78.181 - - [20/Dec/2011:16:36:18 +0800] "GET http://g.ha99y.com/R.asp?P=123.157.218.85:8080 HTTP/1.1" 404 29
```

***error.log:***

```
[Tue Dec 20 15:50:14 2011] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=1008): Create interpreter 'myhost.com:8080|'.
[Tue Dec 20 15:50:14 2011] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=1008): Adding 'E:/eclipse workspace/SubscriptionServer/src' to path.
[Tue Dec 20 15:50:14 2011] [info] [client 66.220.151.121] mod_wsgi (pid=1008, process='', application='myhost.com:8080|'): Loading WSGI script 'E:/eclipse workspace/SubscriptionServer/src/business/dispatcher.py'.
[Tue Dec 20 16:36:19 2011] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=1008): Create interpreter 'myhost.com|'.
[Tue Dec 20 16:36:19 2011] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=1008): Adding 'E:/eclipse workspace/SubscriptionServer/src' to path.
[Tue Dec 20 16:36:19 2011] [info] [client 124.237.78.181] mod_wsgi (pid=1008, process='', application='myhost.com|'): Loading WSGI script 'E:/eclipse workspace/SubscriptionServer/src/business/dispatcher.py'.
```

Answer (score 1):

You likely modified the WSGI script file which caused mod_wsgi to reload it.

Turn off reloading using:

```
WSGIScriptReloading Off
```

Whenever you make code changes then make sure you restart Apache.

Read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode#Reloading_In_Embedded_Mode
  http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIScriptReloading

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I'm one hundred percent sure that I haven't made any code change. Because I left the code running at weekend without changing it and found the issue by log.

Comment: Then post the mod_wsgi parts of Apache configuration. The only other thing I can think of is that you are somehow multi aliasing to same script in a way that it may get loaded into different sub interpreters. The thread classes in this instance would be in different sub interpreters. You can get an idea if this was the case by ensuring that LogLevel is set to 'info' in Apache configuration. That way mod_wsgi will log when WSGI script is loaded/reloaded and into which sub interpreter.

Comment: WSGIScriptAlias / "E:/eclipse workspace/SubscriptionServer/src/business/dispatcher.py"  

WSGIPythonPath "E:/eclipse workspace/SubscriptionServer/src"  


<Directory "E:/eclipse workspace/SubscriptionServer">  

 Order deny,allow  

 Allow from all  

</Directory>

Comment: Hi @Graham, I have got some findings!

Comment: Your server is still listening on port 80 as well as port 8080. Because you haven't explicitly stopped this and haven't got a VirtualHost definition for port 80, then Apache will fallback to using first VirtualHost definition it finds in configuration. It uses a different sub interpreter though because mod_wsgi by default separates requests against different ports into different sub interpreters, except for 80/443 case. Comment out the Listen directive for port 80 in Apache configuration. The request could be probe to see if your site is vulnerable to certain attack.

Comment: In httpd.conf, I only set **Listen 8080**. I'm sure there is no 80 port. This is strange that I only listen to 8080, but create the interpreter with 80.

Comment: So if you try and access port 80 from a web browser it definitely fails? Do you have any mod_rewrite rules, especially any that would force any form of redirect.

Comment: Yes! I can't access the url with port 80. mod_rewrite module is not used.

Comment: Edit your original question and add all the VirtualHost definitions you have. Do you still have one defined for port 80 and does it precede that for port 8080, regardless that no Listen for port 80? What is ServerName/ServerAlias for 8080 and do any host names map to the server which wouldn't be picked up by ServerName/ServerAlias? If there is, and port 80 VirtualHost still exists, then may be falling back to using that in that case.