# Does mod_wsgi create interpreter for each port

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

My develop environment is Windows, which means the Apache MPM could only be **'winnt'**. Here I find the strange thing:

**1**. Apache only listens to 8080 and I have set no virtual hosts, but in error log, why it creates two interpreters for 'myhost.com:8080|' and 'myhost.com|'? It supposes to be only 8080 one.

***access.log:***

```
124.237.78.181 - - [20/Dec/2011:16:36:18 +0800] "GET http://www.baidu.com/ HTTP/1.1" 404 29
```

This request will cause apache to create 80 interpreter(please notice the time). I don't know where it comes from(proxy detecting?). But I can simulate it through **telnet**.

```
telnet myhost.com 8080  
GET http://www.baidu.com/
```

***error.log:***

```
[Tue Dec 20 15:50:14 2011] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=1008): Create interpreter 'myhost.com:8080|'.
[Tue Dec 20 15:50:14 2011] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=1008): Adding 'E:/eclipse workspace/SubscriptionServer/src' to path.
[Tue Dec 20 15:50:14 2011] [info] [client 66.220.151.121] mod_wsgi (pid=1008, process='', application='myhost.com:8080|'): Loading WSGI script 'E:/eclipse workspace/SubscriptionServer/src/business/dispatcher.py'.
[Tue Dec 20 16:36:19 2011] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=1008): Create interpreter 'myhost.com|'.
[Tue Dec 20 16:36:19 2011] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=1008): Adding 'E:/eclipse workspace/SubscriptionServer/src' to path.
[Tue Dec 20 16:36:19 2011] [info] [client 124.237.78.181] mod_wsgi (pid=1008, process='', application='myhost.com|'): Loading WSGI script 'E:/eclipse workspace/SubscriptionServer/src/business/dispatcher.py'.
```

**2**. When I shut down the apache, no matter how many interpreters it creates, it only destroys the 8080 interpreter.

```
[Sun Dec 25 15:49:08 2011] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=4288): Destroying interpreters.
[Sun Dec 25 15:49:08 2011] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=4288): Destroy interpreter 'myhost.com:8080|'.
```

I want apache to create only 8080 interpreter and how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

By default, requests against port 80 and 443 will would be handled in same sub interpreter. Requests against any other port are processed in different interpreter. This is documented in mod_wsgi documentation.

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIApplicationGroup

As to why you are seeing both I don't know because you never followed up to questions when you asked about this before in separate question:

[Variable will be instantiated more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570446/variable-will-be-instantiated-more-than-once)

StackOverflow is not the right forum for trying to debug why your configuration is causing the problem anyway. Use the mod_wsgi mailing list and then can point you at appropriate documentation which tells you how to add debugging to your WSGI application script to work out where the spurious request associated with port 80 is coming from.

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6#Asking_Your_Questions

The documentation is quite clear that if you want help on mod_wsgi you should always use the mailing list in preference to StackOverflow. StackOverflow is a hopeless place for debugging stuff and is not a forum. It is only useful if someone know the exact answer.

Comment: Hi Graham, sorry for my mistake. As I haven't checked the thread in StackOverFlow for days and in case you have not been informed in the old thread, so I make a new one about this. Thx for your answer. I will turn to mod_wsgi mailing list then.